# Set background color of UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have looked around to find a solution for setting the background color of the accessoryView to the same background color as the cell´s contentView.

```
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:178/255.f green:14/255.f blue:12/255.f alpha:0.05];
    cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:178/255.f green:14/255.f blue:12/255.f alpha:0.05];
```

There is a solution that works but only let me use one color for all cells.

```
cell.contentView.superView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Is the only solution to not use the accessoryView and use an image instead?

Thanks!

Comment: the answer is just cell.backgroundColor ... of course when you are **inside a cell class**, it's just self.backgroundColor .  BUT be aware of the separate contentView, **where you may have set a BG colour by default** in storyboard and it would be on top of your cell colour!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I struggled with this one for a little while too and resorted to creating a custom image with the accessory.  But I just found this solution that works well and doesn't require a custom image.  The trick is to change the cell's backgroundView color not the backgroundColor.

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
if (indexPath.row % 2) {
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
} else {
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
cell.backgroundView = myView;
```

No need to change the accessoryView or contentView background colors.  They'll follow automatically.

---

Note for 2014. Very typically you wold use -(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated

So, you'd have a custom cell class, and you'd set the colours for the normal/selected like this...

```
HappyCell.h
@interface HappyCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;
etc...
@end

HappyCell.m
@implementation HappyCell

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
      reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
        {
        }
    return self;
    }

-(void)awakeFromNib
    {
    }

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if(selected)
        {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        .. other setup for selected cell
        }
    else
        {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        .. other setup for normal unselected cell
        }
    }

@end

// to help beginners.......
// in your table view class, you'd be doing this...

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
      numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    return yourDataArray.count;
    }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv
      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    NSInteger thisRow = indexPath.row;
    ContentsCell *cell = [tv
      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellName"
      forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
    // "cellName" must be typed in on the cell, the storyboard
    // it's the "identifier", NOT NOT NOT the restorationID

    [cell setupForNumber: thisRow];
    cell.mainLabel.text = yourDataArray[ thisRow ][@"whatever"];
    cell.otherLabel.text = yourDataArray[ thisRow ][@"whatever"];

    return cell;
    }
```

hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 28):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Using this `UITableViewDelegate` method, you can set the color of cells to different colors. Note that Apple explicitly advise you to make changes to the `backgroundColor` property within the `tableView:willDisplayCell:ForRowAtIndexPath:` method in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which state:

> If you want to change the background color of a cell, do so in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of your table view delegate

Indeed, in iOS 6, changes to the property from anywhere else (like the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method) would have no effect at all. That no longer seems to be the case in iOS 7, but Apple's advice to modify the property from within `tableView:willDisplayCell:ForRowAtIndexPath:` remains (without any explanation).

For alternating colors, do something like this example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];    
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a pretty cryptic explanation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7) that goes: _...If the delegate chooses to implement this method, it can make last-minute changes to the cell object before it is displayed. With this method, the delegate should change only state-based properties that were set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color, and not content._

Comment: ...which to me is more about NOT setting content in willDisplayCell rather than the opposite

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGreyColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

For all lines with the same color

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:6.0/255.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:145.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];
```

For 2 colors

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:6.0/255.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:145.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f];

    if ((cell.backgroundColor = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? [UIColor colorWithRed:6.0/255.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:145.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f] : [UIColor colorWithRed:2.0/255.0 green:68.0/255.0 blue:80.0/255.0 alpha:1.0f]))){
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who might stumble on this and wants to set their `UITableViewCell` background to a **pattern or texture** rather than a solid color, you can do so like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.png"]];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best option to have different backgrounds and what not would probably be to make your own TableViewCell implementation, in there you can put the logic to show whatever you want based on content or index etc.

Comment: This question applies to custom/subclassed UITableViewCells as well