# iPhone/Cocoa Touch - Change UITableViewCell background from one color to another

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I want to change the color of a UITableViewCell slowly from one color to another **WHILE** I m holding (tap holding) the cell for a specific duration.

After that duration it should do a action.. Its just like Whatsapps row selection on Android..
It starts first bright and ends with a darkest color..

I tried that already with a gesture recognizer but that didn't work..

Is that possible? I would appreciate a sample code.

**EDIT 1:**

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CostumEventCell *cell = [eventsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(252/255.0) green:(213/255.0) blue:(183/255.0) alpha:1]];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^(void) {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(85/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1]];
    }];
}
```

** EDIT 2 (with gesture recognizer):**

```
- (void) createGestureListener{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onLongPress:)];
    longPressRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.eventsTable addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];


}

    -(void)onLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)pGesture
    {

        CGPoint touchPoint = [pGesture locationInView:self.view];
        NSIndexPath* row = [eventsTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

        if (pGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        {
            //Do something to tell the user!
            NSLog(@"Tap started");
            CostumEventCell *cell = [eventsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:row];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^(void) {
                [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(252/255.0) green:(213/255.0) blue:(183/255.0) alpha:1]];
                [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(85/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1]];
            }];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what didn't work?  Putting something like "[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{ cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; }];" in a gesturerecognizer selector works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make my own cell class as a subclass of UITableViewCell and intercept the touches in it.

Override touchesBegan like this

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^(void) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(252/255.0) green:(213/255.0) blue:(183/255.0) alpha:1]];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(204/255.0) green:(85/255.0) blue:(0/255.0) alpha:1]];
    }];
}
```

and then maybe touchesEnded like this to turn the colors off--or do whatever you want from the cell.

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }];
}
```

Comment: You need a custom class.  Your xib can point to that class instead of UITableViewCell.  Make your own class that is a subclass of UITableViewCell and put that code in the subclass.

Comment: i did that but now its not even get the selectedcolor.. and the color transformation is not working. This is making my head explode for 2days..

Comment: I have a sample project that works just fine.  I'll see if I can post it somewhere.

Comment: ill accept your answer cuz your sample is exactly what i need... i didnt fixed yet but i think i will. ty

Answer (score 0):

You may add a UIButton on the Cell, then handle the touch down event by adding facade animation.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` can animate changes in `backgroundColor`. Whenever a row is selected, set it to the starting color and then call `animateWithDuration:animations:` to animate to the new color.

```
//set first color here
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
     // set final color here.
}];
```

**EDIT**: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649573/set-background-color-of-uitableviewcell) to know how to properly set the background color of a `UITableviewCell`

Comment: Your code seems right, but I think the problem is that you can't set the background color of the `cell` by setting its `backgroundColor` directly.
You can set `backgroundColor` of the `contentView` property of the cell, or provide a `backgroundView`. **Check the link in the edited solution for details**.